# Change Customer to Company on Magento Administrator Dashboard

Tags: magento

On the Magento administrator Dashboard I'm looking to update the 'Last 5 Orders' block so that instead of displaying the customer name, it shows the company billing name instead.

My understanding is that this can't be done using the standard reports collection, I've seen examples for doing this on the main sales grid screen, but not on the dashboard. To add further complexity this is for the latest version of Magento 1.6.1.0 and it appears the method of doing this may have changed somewhere around 1.4.

The file I believe needs editing is:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php
```

Hopefully this is one of those 'easy when you know how' solutions that lots of people can benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code
PS : I haven't got time to test this code block.

The code block available in the :

> app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Dashboard\Tab\Customers\Most.php

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => $this->__('Customer Name'),
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => $this->__('Number of Orders'),
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
        'type'      => 'number'
    ));
```

and here is the sample link that you can override the magento admin sales grid 
[Override Admin Sales Order Search Grid](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/override_admin_sales_order_search_grid)